# Convert the hexa string into hex string byte array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, hex, byte

I am having a hard time trying to convert a String containing the hex string representation to its corresponding hex string byte array.

I tried this code

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) (((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s
                .charAt(i + 1), 16)) & 0xFF);
    }
    return data;
}
```

It's not the exact value what i am looking for above code conveting "FF" --> -1.

Expecting is "FF" --> byte[] { FF }.

Ex : **"01FF0A2357F01A"** result should be like this **byte[] { 01 FF 0A 12 57 F0 1A }.**

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A byte array contains bytes, not characters. bytes are numbers, going from -127 to 128. One alternate way of representing them is to use a pair of characters from 0 to F: that's called the hexadecimal representation. Just like the numer 1000 can be represented as a string using 1K. But 1K still means the number 1000.

Comment: @JBNizetI am expecting like this is "FF0A" --> byte[]  {FF, OA}

Comment: @Scary Wombat .. This is not a duplicate question that marked answer returning "FF" as -1 but i am expecting it as "FF" --> byte [] { FF }

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectations are not quite right but,

```
    String hex = "ff";
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(hex, 16);
    System.out.println(i);
    Byte b = i.byteValue();
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(i));
```

`FF` is the string representation of `-1` in hex

Comment: Is it possible to create a byte array of string "FF" instead of representation as "-1".